How to find apt repositories
I have linux 22.04.4 and apt, for that version of ubuntu, has zsh as version 5.8.
I was having a problem with zsh and wanted to upgrade to 5.9 because that's what a contributor of zsh said. So I searched that I needed to add a new apt repository as Jammy only goes up to zsh 5.8 and Mantic goes up to 5.9, but I couldn't find a way to find the apt repository url for mantic. Eventually I did find it, but it was in an obscure site. What is the standard way of finding official ubuntu apt repository urls?

Adding repos from other Ubuntu versions, even official ones, is a swell way to break your package system.

The only official repositories for Ubuntu are the Ubuntu Repositories.  There is no direct way to determine if a given piece of software has Ubuntu packages in separately maintained repositories.  The base repositories exist at http://archive.ubuntu.com and any number of country-specific mirror servers that're in the DNS / system rotations.
While those separate repos may be 'official' for the specific projects, there is no centrally maintained database of known third party package repositories that serve packages for Ubuntu.  "Official" for Ubuntu means the actual Ubuntu Repositories, nothing else.  You use any third party repositories at your own risk as they are not supported by Canonical or the Ubuntu Security Team, and may be subject to breaking changes, updates, etc. from upstream developers.

yes , but I think mantic is an official Ubuntu repository , as it's the Ubuntu realease Ubuntu 23.10.1 (Mantic Minotaur). So how would I be able to find the apt repository url  for this OFFICIAL UBUNTU  REPOSITORY

@Ledrake There is no 23.10.1.  That's not an official Ubuntu version.  If you want to find the official repository URLs, look at your /etc/apt/sources.list on a default install, or on the cloud images, or refer to the standard archives of http://archive.ubuntu.com/ which is the base repository URL. It's always been archive.ubuntu.com since the dawn, but that is only for Ubuntu's repositories, and not third party repos like some software projects run.

Ubuntu sources have moved to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources
